# Using Protractor Cucumber JS: When running a test, the test passes when it shouldn't

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor, cucumber

I'm writing a test where I should log in. It passed given the proper inputs but when I change its password/username to garbage, it still passes. I'm new to this and I really think I missed something here. Please help me out?

Here is my code:

-------------------[config.js]-------------------------

```js
    'use strict';
    
    var config = {
    
        seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        specs           : [ 'test/e2e/features/login/login.feature' ],
        baseUrl         : http://someUrl.com,
        capabilities    : {
            browserName : 'chrome'
        },
    
        onPrepare   : function () {
            var width  = 1024;
            var height = 600;
    
            global.dv = browser.driver;
    
            dv.manage().window().setSize( width, height );
    
            // This will tell the Protractor not to wait for angular
            global.isAngularSite = function(flag) {
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
            };
        },
    
        framework : 'cucumber',
    
        cucumberOpts : {
            // define your step definitions in this file
            require : 'test/e2e/features/login/spec.js',
            format  : 'pretty'
        }
    
    };
    
    exports.config = config;
```

-------------------[login.feature]-------------------------

```
Feature: Login

  As a user, I should be able to have login creadentials so that I can login to the system

Scenario: Valid login creadentials

    Given I login using valid creadentials

    Then I should be logged in
```

-------------------[page.js]-------------------------

```js
    'use strict';
    
    ( function () {
    
        var navigate = function () {
            browser.get( '' );
        };
    
        var login = function ( username, password ) {
            this.username.sendKeys( username );
            this.password.sendKeys( password );
            this.loginButton.click();
        };
    
        var LoginPage = function () {
            this.username     = dv.findElement( by.css( '[data-ptor="loginEmail"]' ) );
            this.password     = dv.findElement( by.css( '[data-ptor="loginPassword"]' ) );
            this.loginButton  = dv.findElement( by.css( '[data-ptor="loginButton"]' ) );
        };
    
        LoginPage.prototype.navigate = navigate;
        LoginPage.prototype.login    = login;
    
        module.exports = LoginPage;
    
    } )();
```

-------------------[homepage.js]-------------------------

```js
    'use strict';
    
    ( function () {
    
        var navigate = function () {
    
            browser.get( '/#home' );
    
        };
    
        var HomePage = function () {
            this.homeIndicator = dv.getCurrentUrl();
        };
    
        HomePage.prototype.navigate = navigate;
    
        module.exports = HomePage;
    } )();
```

-------------------[spec.js]-------------------------

```js
    'use strict';
    
    var LoginPage      = require( '../../features/login/page.js' );
    
    var HomePage       = require( '../../features/homepage/homepage.js' );
    
    var chai           = require( 'chai' );
    
    var chaiAsPromised = require( 'chai-as-promised' );
    
    chai.use( chaiAsPromised );
    
    var expect = chai.expect;
    
    module.exports = function () {
    
        var loginPage;
        var homePage;
    
        this.Before( function ( callback ) {
    
            loginPage = new LoginPage();
            homePage  = new HomePage();
            isAngularSite(false);
            loginPage.navigate();
            callback();
    
        } );
    
        this.After( function ( callback ) {
            //logout
            callback();
        } );
    
        // First Scenario
        this.Given( 'I login using valid creadentials', function ( callback ) {
            loginPage.login( 'username', 'password' ); //valid creadential
            callback();
        } );
    
        this.Then( 'I should be logged in', function ( callback ) {
            expect(homePage.homeIndicator).toEqual('http://someUrl.com/#home');
            callback();
        } );
    
    };
```

Comment: this is by the way a test for a non-angular app..

Comment: Maybe the check you are doing is not ok and it applies for both cases valid/invalid. I think you should review the 'I should be logged in' step and see what you validate.

Comment: what is the application state after performing these steps? Does it show the home page even on entering incorrect credentials? Or shows any errors?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `callback()`, try using  `setTimeout(callback, 1000);`

Comment: Could you please add some explanation about why doing this will help the OP?